# ServiceForbiddenException Linking Channel

Tags: youtube-api

I have an application that creates and uploads videos for customers. Before attempting the upload the customer grants authorization and the resulting access and refresh tokens are saved. It sometimes happens that the customer does not have a YouTube channel associated with their Google Account. I detect this and create a channel for them. This normally works fine. But not always. Here's an example of where creating the channel failed:

```
Obtaining access token for Customer
post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
HTTP Response: 200
{
 "access_token" : "_new_access_token_",
 "token_type" : "Bearer",
 "expires_in" : 3600
}

Uploading video '_video_name_' for Customer
post http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
    Authorization: Bearer _new_access_token_
    GData-Version: 2.1
    X-GData-Key: key=_GData_Key_
    Slug: n3n1xs.mp4
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="51d366cb05b71"
    Content-Length: 255958407
    Connection: close
HTTP Response: 403
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:service</domain><code>youtube_signup_required</code></error></errors>

Obtaining channel names for Customer
get https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/suggest/username?hint=CustomerNameVT&fields=entry%2Ftitle
    GData-Version: 2.1
    X-GData-Key: key=_GData_Key_
HTTP Response: 200
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'><entry><title>CustomerNameVT</title></entry><entry><title>VTCustomerName</title></entry><entry><title>VTNameCustomer</title></entry><entry><title>CustomerVTName</title></entry><entry><title>CustomerNameVT1</title></entry><entry><title>NameCustomerVT</title></entry><entry><title>NameVTCustomer</title></entry></feed>

Linking YT channel for Customer (CustomerNameVT)
put https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default
    Authorization: Bearer _new_access_token_
    Content-Type: application/atom+xml
    GData-Version: 2.1
    X-GData-Key: key=_GData_Key_
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><yt:username>CustomerNameVT</yt:username></entry>
HTTP Response: 403
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceForbiddenException</code><internalReason>Forbidden</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Notice that the requested name is the first one suggested by the suggest username api. As far as I can see this should work. It usually does. What's wrong this time?

Answer (score 0):

The API for linking a Google Account to a new channel is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_deprecated).

Our [current recommendation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel) is to explicitly take users through a web-based linking process, starting at https://youtube.com/create_channel (or the m.youtube.com equivalent).

Comment: For most of our customers the sequence looks like this: sign up for a Google account, authorize the upload, then create a YT channel. That's asking a lot. After granting the authorization, Google transfers back to our site. Unfortunately, it seems there is no way for the create channel process to do that. The 'next' link appears to be restricted to youtube.com. Cross-site scripting rules prevent monitoring that. So, the way we've decided to handle this to ask for authorization, then with each upload check if they have a YT account. If so, we use it, if not we upload to our own channel.

Comment: I've heard some internal rumblings that if you use the Google+ Sign-In button to handle OAuth 2 for you, in the future you may be guaranteed to that the end result will be authorization for a channel that supports uploads, since YouTube channels linked to Google+ accounts do support uploads. https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in